# Is there a way to implement mapcar in Common Lisp using only applicative programming and avoiding recursion or iteration as programming styles?

Tags: recursion, iteration, common-lisp, map-function

I am trying to learn Common Lisp with the book *Common Lisp: A gentle introduction to Symbolic Computation*. In addition, I am using SBCL, Emacs and Slime.

In chapter 7, the author suggests there are three **styles** of programming the book will cover: recursion, iteration and applicative programming.

I am interested on the last one. This style is famous for the **applicative operator** `funcall` which is the primitive responsible for other applicative operators such as `mapcar`.

Thus, with an educational purpose, I decided to implement my own version of `mapcar` using `funcall`:

```
(defun my-mapcar (fn xs)
  (if (null xs)
      nil
      (cons (funcall fn (car xs))
            (my-mapcar fn (cdr xs)))))
```

As you might see, I used **recursion** as a programming style to build an iconic applicative programming function.

It seems to work:

```
CL-USER> (my-mapcar (lambda (n) (+ n 1)) (list 1 2 3 4))
(2 3 4 5)

CL-USER> (my-mapcar (lambda (n) (+ n 1)) (list ))
NIL

;; comparing the results with the official one

CL-USER> (mapcar (lambda (n) (+ n 1)) (list ))
NIL

CL-USER> (mapcar (lambda (n) (+ n 1)) (list 1 2 3 4))
(2 3 4 5)
```

Is there a way to implement mapcar **without** using recursion or iteration? Using only **applicative** programming as a style?

Thanks.

Obs.: I tried to see how it was implemented. But it was not possible

```
CL-USER> (function-lambda-expression #'mapcar)
NIL
T
MAPCAR
```

I also used Emacs `M-.` to look for the documentation. However, the points below did not help me. I used [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/sbcl/sbcl/ci/master/tree/src/compiler/) to find the files below:

```
/usr/share/sbcl-source/src/code/list.lisp
  (DEFUN MAPCAR)
/usr/share/sbcl-source/src/compiler/seqtran.lisp
  (:DEFINE-SOURCE-TRANSFORM MAPCAR)
/usr/share/sbcl-source/src/compiler/fndb.lisp
  (DECLAIM MAPCAR SB-C:DEFKNOWN)
```

Comment: When you get a list of files for inspection in Slime (which you can also do by placing the cursor on the item of interest, e.g., `mapcar`, and pressing `M-.`), you can view any one of them by moving the cursor the the line of interest (e.g., `(:DEFINE-SOURCE-TRANSFORM MAPCAR)`). If you do that, you will see that the function `mapfoo-transform` may be of some interest, so press `M-.` on that. I discussed this process in the answer I linked to under your previous question.

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping again :). I actually used M-. to get the info above. It was M-x on my text but that was a typo. I am checking out mapfoo-transform too. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mapcar` *is* by itself a primitive *applicative operator* (pag. 220 of Common Lisp: A gentle introduction to Symbolic Computation). So, if you want to rewrite it in an applicative way, you should use some other primitive applicative operator, for instance [`map`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_map.htm) or [`map-into`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_map_in.htm). For instance, with `map-into`:

```
CL-USER> (defun my-mapcar (fn list &rest lists)
           (apply #'map-into (make-list (length list)) fn list lists))
MY-MAPCAR
CL-USER> (my-mapcar #'1+ '(1 2 3))
(2 3 4)
CL-USER> (my-mapcar #'+ '(1 2 3) '(10 20 30) '(100 200 300))
(111 222 333)
```

Answer (score 2):

Technically, recursion can be implemented as follows:

```lisp
(defun fix (f)
   (funcall (lambda (x) (funcall x x))
            (lambda (x) (funcall f (lambda (&rest y) (apply (funcall x x) y))))))
```

Notice that `fix` does not use recursion in any way. In fact, we could have only used `lambda` in the definition of `f` as follows:

```lisp
(defconstant fix-combinator 
             (lambda (g) (funcall 
                          (lambda (x) (funcall x x))
                          (lambda (x) (funcall 
                                       g 
                                       (lambda (&rest y) (apply (funcall x x) 
                                                                 y)))))))

(defun fix-2 (f)
  (funcall fix-combinator f))
```

The `fix-combinator` constant is more commonly known as the y combinator.

It turns out that `fix` has the following property:

Evaluating `(apply (fix f) list)` is equivalent to evaluating `(apply (funcall f (fix f)) list)`. Informally, we have `(fix f) = (funcall f (fix f))`.

Thus, we can define `map-car` (I'm using a different name to avoid package lock) by

```lisp
(defun map-car (func lst)
  (funcall (fix (lambda (map-func) (lambda (lst) ; We want mapfunc to be (lambda (lst) (mapcar func lst))
    (if (endp lst) 
        nil 
        (cons (funcall func (car lst)) 
              (funcall map-func (cdr lst)))))))
    lst))
```

Note the lack of recursion or iteration.

That being said, generally `mapcar` is just taken as a primitive notion when using the "applicative" style of programming.

Answer (score 1):

Another way you can implement `mapcar` is by using the more general `reduce` function (a.k.a. fold). Let's name the user-provided function `f` and define `my-mapcar`.

The `reduce` function carries an accumulator value that builds up the resulting list, here it is going take a value `v`, a sublist `rest`, and call `cons` with `(funcall f v)` and `rest`, so as to build a list.

More precisely, here `reduce` is going to implement a right-fold, since `cons` is right-associative (e.g. the recursive list is the "right" hand side, ie. the second argument of `cons`, e.g. `(cons a (cons b (cons nil)))`).

In order to define a right-fold with `reduce`, you pass `:from-end t`, which indicates that it builds-up a value from the last element and the initial accumulator to obtain a new accumulator value, then the second to last element with that new accumulator to build a new accumulator, etc. This is how you ensure that the resulting elements are in the same order as the input list.

In that case, the reducing function takes its the current element as its first argument, and the accumulator as a second argument.

Since the type of the elements and the type of the accumulator are different, you need to pass an `:initial-value` for the accumulator (the default behavior where the initial-value is taken from the list is for functions like `+` or `*`, where the accumulator is in the same domain as the list elements).

With that in mind, you can write it as follows:

```
(defun my-map (f list)
  (reduce (lambda (v rest) (cons (funcall f v) rest))
          list
          :from-end t
          :initial-value nil))
```

For example:

```
(my-map #'prin1-to-string '(0 1 2 3))
; => ("0" "1" "2" "3")
```